# PayPal Sandbox IPN doesn't upload the values in the Database table

Tags: php

For some strange reason the mechanism, after having worked for a few months, now no longer work. The most frustrating thing is that I haven't the slightest touch the structure of the code and the database.

The situation is this:

The user makes the purchase by pressing a button that has a script capable of uploadin the values of license and user within my database.
To purchase completed, the user receives the purchase confirmation email, but the license isn't sent, in fact the license isn't loaded into the database.
I still can receive the confirmation email from PayPal that someone bought my product.

What's even more strange is when I try to use the SandBoxIPN of PayPal developer's, it seems that the two test account that I created while running the same simulation mode (purchase - sale) somehow not receive the mail confirming the purchase or buys occurred.

I don't know what's going on. What I propose to do to overcome this problem effectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem. My hosting blocked the server to server connections, so I've activate this functionality and now the script working right!